# Sorting two dimensional array by columns in C#

Tags: c#, arrays, multidimensional-array

I want to sort two-dimensional array. Instead of ordering for the first dimension I want to order the inner dimension.

For example if initial array is like this:

```
{{4, 1, 3},
{6, 5, 2},
{0, 9, 8}}
```

Then if we sort array by first row, result will be:

```
{{1, 3, 4},
{5, 2, 6},
{9, 8, 0}}
```

I managed doing this by transposing the array, ordering and transposing again. But is there a better way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Hmmmm this is a bit of an odd one and I actually misunderstood it at first. There are ways to do this but none of them that I can think of are really nice. Personally I think I would so something like

```
public class Matrix
{
    private List<RowGroup> _groups;

    public Matrix(List<List<int>> matrix)
    { 
        //Removed for simplicity
    }

    public void SortMaxtrixByRow(int rowNumber)
    {
        this._groups.Sort((r1, r2) =>
        {
            return r1.Col[rowNumber].CompareTo(r2.Col[rowNumber]);
        });
    }
    public class RowGroup
    {
        public List<int> Col;
        public RowGroup(List<int> col)
        {
            Col = col;
        }
    }
}
```

This is doing something similar to your transposing. The main benefit would be that its an object so if you had to do multiple sorts on the same set it wouldn't need to re-transpose it over and over again.

Other than this you could copy the desired array and sort it then compare each value to the original to see how it moved and move the other rows accordingly but that is only assuming that you are using unique values in each row, writing your own sorting algorithm so you could be sure which index, or are okay with there being multiple "correct" answers.

Comment: Hi Zack, thank you for your answer but I want to order columns not rows unfortunately.
Similar to you can be achieved with 
`list.Sort((a, b) => a[rowNumber].CompareTo(b[rowNumber]));` or
`list.OrderBy(x => x[rowNumber]).ToList();`